# Intellij IDEA - Trigger code sugestions for PHP using :: and -> with a space after them?

Tags: php, intellij-idea

Am using Intellij IDEA for my PHP code but am having some issues with the code suggestion.

If I use the double colon or arrow without a space after them, then code suggestions work fine.

```
$animal ->
$animal ::
```

However I like to add spacing before and after those operators, but Intellij IDEA doesn't detect the space after the operator, so I get no suggestions.

Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: Can I ask why? There's literally no accepted coding standard that does that.

Comment: Because it's our preference.  The group of programmers on the project all prefer the spacing around operators, as it's more readable.  Right now when I accept a suggestion, I have to go back and add the spaces around them, which slows me down.

Comment: Fair enough I guess. Unfortunately I don't think that option exists by default in Storm. Or at least I'm not aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to [work](http://recordit.co/WuQDdvSE6v) with `->` by default.
It also works with non-static methods after `::` for no reason.

This behavior is not configurable, so you'll have to [submit](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=WI) a usability issue.

Comment: Edited my question.  I should have been more clear when I wrote it.  I actually meant a space after the operator.  But I assume your answer is still correct in regards to there being no way to configure it?

Comment: That is correct. Although you can invoke completion manually in both cases with the space after.